# How to measure disk and network IO more frequently than a second?

Tags: monitoring, measure

I am running some experiments that use cpu, disk, and network resources.
(by the way, I use Cent OS 7)
I want to measure its cpu, disk, and network resource usage.

Some tools I know (dstat, iostat) only provides a second as the minimum interval between two measurements.

How can I take several measurements even within a second?
I googled a lot but couldn't find one.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully someone can point you to some tools to do what you want but if not and you're committed you could get the data straight from the source. **iostat** mostly is just parsing special files like */proc/diskstats* and those files are updated whenever you read them. I just did a quick test where I read *diskstats* many times a second and the values were changing with each read.

The **iostat** man page lists the relevant files at the end:

> /proc/stat contains system statistics.
>
> /proc/uptime contains system uptime.
>
> /proc/partitions contains disk statistics (for pre 2.5 kernels that have  been patched).
>
> /proc/diskstats contains disks statistics (for post 2.5 kernels).
>
> /sys contains statistics for block devices (post 2.5 kernels).
>
> /proc/self/mountstats contains statistics for network filesystems.
>
> /dev/disk contains persistent device names.

It's not too hard to find information about what the fields in these files represent. For example:

```
     The /proc/diskstats file displays the I/O statistics
    of block devices. Each line contains the following 14
    fields:
     1 - major number
     2 - minor mumber
     3 - device name
     4 - reads completed successfully
     5 - reads merged
     6 - sectors read
     7 - time spent reading (ms)
     8 - writes completed
     9 - writes merged
    10 - sectors written
    11 - time spent writing (ms)
    12 - I/Os currently in progress
    13 - time spent doing I/Os (ms)
    14 - weighted time spent doing I/Os (ms)
    For more details refer to Documentation/iostats.txt
```

Comment: Awesome. Good to know :D Thx